# How to group_by into a given hash_map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have two models

```
class Author
  # gender
  # name
end

class Book
  # status -> ['published', 'in_progress']
  has_one :author

end
```

I decided to use `group_by` to group the dataset

```
def group_by_gender_by_status
  books.group_by { |book| [book.author.gender, book.status] }
end
```

What do I get instead is this

```
{["male", "published"] => [{BooksRecord}]
["female", "published"] => [{BooksRecord}]
["male", "in_progress"] => [{BooksRecord}]
["female", "in_progress"] => [{BooksRecord}]}
```

My goal is to get this result

```
{
  female: {
    published: 10,
    in_progress: 7
  },
  male: {
    published: 6,
    in_progress: 9
  }
}
```

so that I can access via `data[:male][:published]`, easier to present the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
books.group_by { |book| book.author.gender }
  .transform_values { |books| books.map(&:status).tally }
```

In particular, this is leveraging `Enumerable#tally`, which as added to ruby version 2.7.

You didn't specify which ruby version you're actually using though, so if you're stuck on an older one, you could replace the last line with:

```
.transform_values { |books| books.group_by(&:status).transform_values(&:count) }
```

Comment: I follow this method `.transform_values { |books| books.group_by(&:status).transform_values(&:count) }` since my ruby is `2.6`, unfortunately it returns like this `["male", { "published" => 3, "in_progress" => 10}]`

Comment: I have to do data[0] == 'male' to check if its female or male. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion `books = [{BookRecord}]` --> array

Comment: Its very hard to access `data[0] == "male"` and `data[1] = { :published=> 1, :in_progress => 3}`

Comment: @airsoftFreak Ah, sorry if I got that a little off, but you can convert that to a nice hash by calling `.to_h` on it -- since you have pairs of values, a direct conversion makes sense: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/to_h

Comment: I did this `["male", { "published" => 3, "in_progress" => 10}].to_h` but it doesn't work

Comment: @airsoftFreak I meant on the full object: `[["female", {"published" => 10, "in_progress" => 9}],["male", { "published" => 3, "in_progress" => 10}]].to_h`

Comment: Which gives you `{"female"=>{"published"=>10, "in_progress"=>9}, "male"=>{"published"=>3, "in_progress"=>10}}`

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable#group_by` just creates keys for grouping so you cannot use this exclusively in order to produce your desired result.  Additionally as `books` grows iterating in this fashion will be come less and less performant.

You will be better off putting the grouping and counting on the database so that return is closer to your desired end result, like so:

```
def group_by_gender_by_status
  books.joins(:author)
    .group(Author.arel_attribute(:gender),Book.arel_attribute(:status))
    .count
end
```

This will have a similar resulting Hash as your current `group_by` implementation however the counting and grouping will be performed on the database side before returning:

```
{["male", "published"] => 6,
["female", "published"] => 10,
["male", "in_progress"] => 9,
["female", "in_progress"] => 7}
```

To transition this into your desired nesting we will need to post process this data.

```
def group_by_gender_by_status
  books.joins(:author)
    .group(Author.arel_attribute(:gender),Book.arel_attribute(:status))
    .count
    .each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = {}}) do |((gender,status),counter),obj| 
      obj[gender.to_sym][status.to_sym] = counter
    end 
end
```

The end result will be equivalent to your desired result and by moving the grouping and the counting to the database level it should degrade at a much slower rate.

**Note:** I have no idea where `books` came from or where this method currently exists. The implementation could potentially be further reduced by this understanding.

Comment: Hello thanks for answering i can see using this method elsewhere but at the moment I put this function in a simple delegator for `Publisher class` and it kinda slow down because I need to do query for 1000 publishers, I'm sorry for not being explicit enough regarding the question

Comment: @airsoftFreak I am not sure I understand your comment however if `books` does not load with the `author` the way you are handling it now will be much slower than the proposal and will result in a significant number of database hits (N +1)

Comment: As for that I already do `Book.includes(:author)` to avoid N+1 I'm using simple delegator to do basic processing, but really appreciate the help